# C# inherit from nested class within itself

Tags: inheritance, c#-3.0

Is it possible for a class to inherit from a nested class, or to implement a nested interface in C#?

```
class Outer : Outer.Inner {
    class Inner { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't a class extend its own nested class in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265585/why-cant-a-class-extend-its-own-nested-class-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way that you wrote, no (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kty4k630.aspx)). But if your inner interface is in another class, then you can.

```
public class SomeClass : SomeOtherClass.ISomeInterface {
    public void DoSomething() {}
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public interface ISomeInterface {
        void DoSomething(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this can't be done, but that is the fact!! Anyway... now I am very sad with C#.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the nested type is visible in your scope and not `sealed`, then yes.

**Edit 2:** Do not take this post as any commentary on whether or not you *should* OR *shouldn't* do this, I am only stating that it is allowed. :)

**Edit:** You cannot derive from a type nested within itself, but you *can* implement an interface declared nested in a base type:

```
public class Base
{
    public interface ISomething
    {
    }
}

public class Derived : Base, Base.ISomething
{
}
```